# Which table does the Phone module store data in?

Tags: 7, database

I have installed the [Phone](http://drupal.org/project/phone) module to create a field to take input data as mobile number.

I would like to fetch the mobile number back from database to be displayed in a block. I am not getting the table in which the phone number is stored. So in which table is the phone number data is stored?

Comment: To which entity did you add the phone number field?

Comment: In Drupal there are many other ways than fetching the values from database directly by your code. But it depends on how, when and from which part of the module  you want to fetch data. https://drupal.org/node/1074360

Comment: In Administration->Structure->Profile types and added to main profile as a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this module defines a field, then the table is named after that field. So if your field is called field_phone, the table is called "field_data_field_phone". However, getting the value direct from the database is not the right "Drupal way" to do it.

You say you want to display the phone number in a block, but I assume this is within a specific context, such as on a page for a node or user. One way to do this would be to use the Views module to define a block with whatever fields you wish to display, using a contextual filter to get the node or user ID from the page arguments.

But more information is needed in order to say whether this is the right answer or not.